# `NSMigrationManager.migrateStore()` ignores destination store URL parameter

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

`NSMigrationManager.migrateStore()` fails with `Cannot migrate store in-place: constraint violation during attempted migration`, which is not surprising; what is surprising is that it overwrites destination store URL with the source store URL (both provided in the `userInfo` of the thrown error) and tries to perform migration in-place despite being told otherwise.

Any clues on how to make it migrate to another store (i.e. *not* in-place)?

Comment: I presume that *told otherwise* means you are calling `NSMigrationManager.migrateStore(from:sourceType:options:with:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:)`, and passing *different* URLs to the `from:` and `toDestinationURL:` parameters?  Have you double-checked that?

Comment: Indeed, it takes parameter for destination URL but ignores it.